# "since last year" and "for the last year"

Tags: prepositions

I'm having trouble explaining the sentence below to my student.
He thinks the definite article has something to do with his rationale for using "for" instead of "since".

> Skateboarding can be dangerous. Since the 1960s, thousands of people
> have gone to hospital emergency rooms because of injuries.

I understand the answer in the sentence above is "since". Considering the constructions below however, he asked why "for" can't also be used.

> I have lived in Austin since last year. I have lived in Austin for the
> last year.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 13):

Since last year = since 2019.

For the last year = during the previous 12 months.

*Since* is used in relation to a specific date or period in the past (yesterday, last year, the 1960s). *For* is used of a length of time (a while, an hour, the past week).